# Are there any Shariah ruling on crowdfunding that I should be careful about?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, money, muslim-practices, business

Recently I came to this website https://almabrook.io/ which looks legit. It's pretty appealing and I am considering putting some money as a test run. This will be my first time doing business without a physical encounter with the party.

The point which attracts me the most is that **they claim to be 100% Shariah Compliant** and also allow starting **investing with as low as $100 and choosing multiple businesses** to share your money between them.

I guess as long as my intentions are right $100 is worth giving me a shot.

I am sharing here perhaps to **hear some thoughts of fellow Muslims** and their views on this.

Comment: Just come to check if there are people interested in this. I see that my question was viewed 23 times. I will keep you guys posted - I hope to meet someone with similar interests.